# Holographic Remoting (Hololens 2) connection problem in both Unity and Unreal : TransportConnectionFailed

Tags: unity-game-engine, connection, unreal-engine4, hololens

I'm new in hololens 2 developing and trying to use Holographic Remoting.

Unity 2019 LTS
MRTK 2.5.3
Unreal 4.26
Hololens 2
Win 10
VS 2019

1. In Unity : I follow a popular tutorial,

On HoloLens, go to the Microsoft Store and install the Holographic Remoting Player application.
On HoloLens, start the Holographic Remoting Player application.
In Unity, click the "Windows" menu and select "XR->Holographic Emulation".
Set the simulation mode to the remote device.
For remote computers, please enter the IP address of HOLOLENS.
Click "Connect". You should see the connection status change to "Connected", and you should see the screen appear blank in HoloLens.
Click the "Play" button to start the play mode and experience the application on HoloLens.

What I met:
[Setting in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxtE1.png)
[Setting in Unity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60403.png)

When I start to "Connect", Error there:
Disconnected with error TransportConnectionFailed
UnityEditor.EditorApplication:Internal_CallUpdateFunctions()

2. In Unreal I follow: https://docs.unrealengine.com/zh-CN/SharingAndReleasing/XRDevelopment/AR/HoloLens/QuickStartStreaming/index.html
   https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows/mixed-reality/develop/unreal/tutorials/unreal-uxt-ch6

[Setting in Unreal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jl54n.png)
[Setting in Unreal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRs5h.png)
Similiar error:
LogTemp: Editor connecting to remote HoloLens2: 192.168.19.57
LogWmrHmd: WMRInterop: ConnectToRemoteHoloLens trying to connect to HoloLens2 192.168.19.57
LogWmrHmd: WMRInterop: RemotingDisconnectedEvent: Reason: 12 TransportConnectionFailed
LogHoloLensAR: Warning: HoloLens AR session disconnected from peer

I can connect the device in device portal, and in the Unreal device manager I can also connect my hololens.
[device portal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TJICy.png)
[Unreal device manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bewlb.png)

Anyone meet this problem?

Comment: Is there any error message shown from Holographic Remoting Player in the HoloLens? We found some similar reports from other customers and the error message from App will help us to narrow them down.

Comment: No, it just show "Waiting connection on <MyIPAddress>", nothing happen since I tried to connect it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still didn't find a solution with this configuration (thank you Hernando, but it's not a VPN problem).

However, after I used :

**unity2019LTS-XRSDK-MRTK2.4.0-DefaultXRSDKConfigurationProfile**

All the things work well (whether VPN is on or not).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Could you check that is there any network management software (such as anti-virus software, Firewall, VPN, etc.) is running on your PC? Because we have solved same problems of another customer, and the reason is that he installed VPN software on the PC, which caused UDP port to be blocked. If you still see the same behavior after shutting down the network management software, please open a support ticket through this link: http://aka.ms/hololenssupport